# eigen 3.3.4 Affine3f::rotation get wrong matrix value

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I'm using eigen 3.3.4 for matrix computation, using VS2010 in x64 release mode , the code:

```
void foo(const Eigen::Affine3f& pose){
    cout<<">>>>>>>>>>>>foo\n"
        <<"pose:\n"<<pose.matrix()<<endl
        <<"pose.linear:\n"<<pose.linear()<<endl
        <<"pose.rotation:\n"<<pose.rotation()<<endl
        ;
}//foo

int main() {
    Eigen::Matrix3f R = Eigen::Matrix3f::Identity ();   // * AngleAxisf( pcl::deg2rad(-30.f), Vector3f::UnitX());
    Eigen::Vector3f t;
    t<<0.15,0.15,-0.6;
    Eigen::Affine3f pose = Eigen::Translation3f (t) * Eigen::AngleAxisf (R);
    cout<<"main\n"
        <<"R, t\n"<<R<<endl<<t<<endl
        <<"pose:\n"<<pose.matrix()<<endl
        <<"pose.linear:\n"<<pose.linear()<<endl
        <<"pose.rotation:\n"<<pose.rotation()<<endl
        ;
    foo(pose);
}
```

outputs:

```
main
R, t
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
0.15
0.15
-0.6
pose:
   1    0    0 0.15
   0    1    0 0.15
   0    0    1 -0.6
   0    0    0    1
pose.linear:
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
pose.rotation:
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
>>>>>>>>>>>>foo
pose:
   1    0    0 0.15
   0    1    0 0.15
   0    0    1 -0.6
   0    0    0    1
pose.linear:
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
pose.rotation:
  1.1529e+016             0             0  //<--------WRONG, it should be an Identity Matrix
            0 -1.07373e+008             0
            0             0 -1.07373e+008
```

The output of `pose.rotation` at last gives the wrong matrix value, which looks like an memory access violation to me.

I don't know if it's because of eigen influenced by other lib files (seems impossible since eigen is header-only), my lib dependencies are:

```
g2o_core.lib
g2o_stuff.lib
g2o_types_slam3d.lib
g2o_solver_cholmod.lib
libblas.lib
liblapack.lib
libamd.lib
libcamd.lib
libccolamd.lib
libcholmod.lib
libcolamd.lib
suitesparseconfig.lib
metis.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\Boost\lib\libboost_system-vc100-mt-1_49.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\Boost\lib\libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_49.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\Boost\lib\libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_49.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\Boost\lib\libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-1_49.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\Boost\lib\libboost_iostreams-vc100-mt-1_49.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\Boost\lib\libboost_regex-vc100-mt-1_49.lib
delayimp.lib
..\..\lib\pcl_io_release.lib
..\..\lib\pcl_gpu_utils_release.lib
..\..\lib\pcl_gpu_octree_release.lib
..\..\lib\pcl_filters_release.lib
D:\opencv249\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_videostab249.lib
D:\opencv249\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_ts249.lib
D:\opencv249\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_superres249.lib
D:\opencv249\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_stitching249.lib
D:\opencv249\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_contrib249.lib
..\..\lib\pcl_io_ply_release.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtkWidgets.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtkHybrid.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtkexoIIc.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtkVolumeRendering.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtkRendering.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtkGraphics.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtkverdict.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtkftgl.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtkfreetype.lib
D:\Qt\qt-4.8.6-x64-msvc2010\lib\QtGui4.lib
D:\Qt\qt-4.8.6-x64-msvc2010\lib\QtSql4.lib
D:\Qt\qt-4.8.6-x64-msvc2010\lib\QtCore4.lib
opengl32.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtkIO.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtkDICOMParser.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtkNetCDF_cxx.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtkNetCDF.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtkmetaio.lib
comctl32.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtksqlite.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtkpng.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtktiff.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtkzlib.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtkjpeg.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtkexpat.lib
vfw32.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtkImaging.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtkFiltering.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtkCommon.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8\vtksys.lib
ws2_32.lib
wsock32.lib
D:\Anaconda2\Library\lib\png.lib
D:\Program Files\OpenNI154\Lib64\openNI64.lib
..\..\lib\pcl_gpu_containers_release.lib
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.0\lib\x64\cudart_static.lib
..\..\lib\pcl_sample_consensus_release.lib
..\..\lib\pcl_search_release.lib
..\..\lib\pcl_octree_release.lib
..\..\lib\pcl_kdtree_release.lib
..\..\lib\pcl_common_release.lib
D:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\FLANN\lib\flann_s.lib
D:\opencv249\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_nonfree249.lib
D:\opencv249\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_ocl249.lib
D:\opencv249\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_gpu249.lib
D:\opencv249\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_photo249.lib
D:\opencv249\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_objdetect249.lib
D:\opencv249\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_legacy249.lib
D:\opencv249\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_video249.lib
D:\opencv249\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_ml249.lib
D:\opencv249\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_calib3d249.lib
D:\opencv249\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_features2d249.lib
D:\opencv249\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_highgui249.lib
D:\opencv249\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_imgproc249.lib
D:\opencv249\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_flann249.lib
D:\opencv249\build\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_core249.lib
```

Comment: I don't have MSVC 2010 and it obviously works well with any other compiler. What if you include Eigen/Dense and iostream only? What if you try with another MSVC version? My guess is an MSVC 2010 issue...

Comment: I just tried it with VS2010 Professional and am unable to reproduce. Do you have an MCVE that actually produces the issue? Also, add all relevant VS version (exact, not 2010), compiler flags, etc.

Comment: Related: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=1564 (MSVC 2010 generally has problems with Eigen >3.2.x)